# How to make that was only one function fetchData?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function `apiFunction` inside the useEffect, which make request to the server:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(currentPage, searchInput ) {
      try {

       const res = await apiFunction ('api/categories', { method: 'GET'}, currentPage, searchInput);

          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listCategory: res.data,
            currentPage: res.page,
            buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(res.total / res.perPage)
         }));

      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData(value.currentPage, value.searchInput); 
  }, [value.currentPage, value.searchInput]);
```

Function `apiFunction` is in a separate file and looks like this:

```
export const apiFunction = async (url, args, valuePage) => { 
  const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}${url}?page=${valuePage}&q=${valueFilter}`, {
   ...args,
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8 ",
      "Accept": 'application/json',
      ...args.headers,  
    },
  });

 return response.json();      
}
```

This function was created simply for convenience. But now I dont need this function. I need that code from `apiFunction` was inside function `fetchData`. That is, that the function `apiFunction`did not exist at all.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace the apiFunction with fetch call in your component like below

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(currentPage, searchInput) {
      try {
        const resJson = await fetch(`${apiUrl}api/categories?page=${currentPage}`, {
          method: 'GET'
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8 ",
            Accept: "application/json",
          }
        });
        const res = await resJson.json();
        setValue(prev => ({
          ...prev,
          listCategory: res.data,
          currentPage: res.page,
          buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(res.total / res.perPage)
        }));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData(value.currentPage, value.searchInput);
  }, [value.currentPage, value.searchInput]);
```

Comment: Dude someone is trying to help you. Atleast be respectful. The header are there in the post. PLease have a look at it. Also there is an async-await syntax

Comment: Sorry but some people wrote anything quickly, and they want that answer to mark as right

Comment: @roki Sure, but people are here to help and even if they wrote something wrong its not correct to be disrespectful because they also tried to help. Its like abusing someone who is trying to pull you out of the well

Comment: Where is the GET method gone?

Comment: fetch by default is GET

Comment: I uderstand, but I need that he was present because in my app I have many request with method POST, PUT. And that I dont create many simmiliar topics better to show you what it should with him

Comment: Updated the answer, if only you went through the API documentation of fetch yourself, you would understand better and will not have to ask others for code